# Compiled classes are not included in generated Jar

Tags: ant, build

I am creating a jar bundle using ant build script. The problem is that the .class files are not included in the generated .jar file. I have also tried the {build.dest} in making the jar, but with no effect.

remaining all the files i require are in .jar file.

Here is my build script

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project name="TaskNodeBundle" default="all" basedir=".">
    <!-- Sets variables which can later be used. -->
    <!-- The value of a property is accessed via ${} -->
    <property name="bundlename" value="task-node-bundle" />
    <property name="src.dir" location="../src" />
    <property name="lib.dir" location="../lib" />
    <property name="build.dir" location="/buildoutput" />
    <property name="build.dest" location="../build/dest" />


    <!--
        Create a classpath container which can be later used in the ant task
    -->
    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}/">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
        <delete dir="${build.dest}" />
    </target>

    <!-- Deletes the existing build directory -->
    <target name="mkdir" depends="clean">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dest}"/>
    </target>


    <!-- Compiles the java code -->
    <target name="compile" depends="mkdir">
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dest}" classpathref="classpath" />
    </target>

    <target name="package-bundle" depends="compile" description="Generates the bundle" >
        <jar destfile="${build.dest}/${bundlename}.jar" manifest="${src.dir}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <include name="**/**.class" />
                <include name="**/**.properties"/>
                <include name="/META-INF/**.*" />
                <include name="/META-INF/spring/**.*" />
            </fileset>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="all" depends="package-bundle">
    </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, what do you mean by "tried {build.dest} in making the jar"?

Whatever, you need to take a look at this part of your build:

```
<jar destfile="${build.dest}/${bundlename}.jar" manifest="${src.dir}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
        <include name="**/**.class" />
        <include name="**/**.properties"/>
        <include name="/META-INF/**.*" />
        <include name="/META-INF/spring/**.*" />
    </fileset>
</jar>
```

1. You compiled class files are in `${build.dest}`, so you should use ${build.dest} as the root dir for the nested `<fileset>` of the `<jar>` task. But now you are pointing the `<fileset>` to your source code folder.
2. You should avoid putting the generated jar file in the same directory where the class files are. For example, you can put the jar in ${dist.dir}, which is another directory.

So try this:

You have a property:

```
<property name="dist.dir" value="../build/dist" />
```

And then,

```
<jar destfile="${dist.dir}/${bundlename}.jar" manifest="${src.dir}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
    <fileset dir="${build.dest}">
        <include name="**/*.class" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.properties"/>
        <include name="/META-INF/**/*.*" />
        <include name="/META-INF/spring/**/*.*" />
    </fileset>
</jar>
```

Comment: Hey, I saw your edit. Of course you can use ${build.dest} to store the jar file; however, as a common practice, I recommend to put the compiled class files and the generated jar file in different driectories. For example, a Netbeans project's class files are in `project/build/classes`, while the generated jar file is in `project/dist`.

Comment: great tip, i will keep that in mind and then there is no need to edit. thank you. i really appreciate it